# Unable to ping to an instance launched in openstack.

Tags: openstack

I have installed open stack using devstack. Launched an cirros image. I can connect to the instance from VNC console but unable to ping to the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a floating IP to that instance. After that you'll be able to access the instance by that floating IP.

If you want to access any extra services on your instances you will also need to configure a proper security group and assign your instances to it.

**NOTE:** If you are running devstack inside a VM that is behind NAT, you won't be able to ping instances from outside that devstack VM without proper networking hacks.

Answer (score 4):

You should configure your security group to allow incoming ICMP (ping) traffic, and also TCP port 22 (ssh).
You can configure the security group from the Openstack web dashboard.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Barak's answer. For reference - here are shell commands to configure rules:

```
$nova --no-cache secgroup-add-rule default icmp -1 -1 0.0.0.0/0
$nova --no-cache secgroup-add-rule default tcp 22 22 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: I have followed as you said but I am still unable to PING or SSH to instance. I Ubuntu 12.04 inside VMWare  WorkStation and OpenStack Havana (via DevStack) installed in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem now. I'm deploying OpenStack on 2 nodes, and instances can be accessed by VNC (I think it's more or less the same with devstack on one node).

The problem is I didn't assigned floating IP to a VM. Plus, br-ex must add a physical interface that connect to outside network. You can check by typing:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl show
```

And see if br-ex have an interface or not. If not, try to add an interface:

```
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br-ex eth0
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue of not being able to connect to Horizon from the host machine after running the "default single machine" Devstack install on a Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM (Virtualbox).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure DNS has been initiated on the virtual machine. I had this problem before and it turned out that DNS wasn't initiated on VM spin up

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are using NAMESPACE # ip netns
if yes you can find out your Router ID inoutput like this :
qrouter-3d5ce39b-8048-4bf5-9999-529295bfb34c

Now you can try ping using your namespace:

ip netns exec qrouter-3d5ce39b-8048-4bf5-9999-529295bfb34c ping 192.168.0.7

Hope this help